# How do I check for when my control obtains or changes the visual parent?

Tags: wpf, events, parent, visual-tree

I want to hook my control's visual parent's events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `OnVisualParentChanged()` method to be notified when ever your visual parent changes.

Note that it is almost always a bad idea to actually use this:  In 99% of cases the data template should take care of hooking up related controls by setting their properties, or it is better handled with attached inherited properties.  But for the other 1% there is `OnVisualParentChanged()`.